# Cakephp Data Validation: Checking if at least one field is populated and multiple rules not validating

Tags: validation, cakephp

Folks,

I'm trying to ensure at least one of two fields (last_name or email) is being populated. Each field also has multiple rules. I'm using CakePHP version 2.4.2.

The problem I have at the moment, after multiple permutations of updating and/or moving around the use 'last', 'allowEmpty', 'required', etc, is that the fields just aren't validating at all, or aren't executing all the rules when a field is populated.

Any advice on how to modify the code below to achieve the following behaviour is much appreciated:
1. One of the two fields must be populated;
2. The other rules attached to each field must validate as well (i.e. if a last name is passed, then it must be between 2 and 45 chars and alphanumeric only)

Here's the model code:

```
public $validate = array(
    'last_name'=> array(
        'needOne' => array (
            'required' => FALSE,
            'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            'last' => TRUE,
            'rule' => array('checkOne','last_name'),
            'message' => 'You must enter at least a contact name or email address.'
         ),
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule'   => 'alphaNumeric',
            'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
        ),
        'between' => array(
            'rule'  => array('between', 2, 45),
            'message' => 'Between 2 to 45 characters'
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'needOne' => array (
            'required' => FALSE,
            'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            'last' => TRUE,
            'rule' => array('checkOne','email'),
            'message' => 'You must enter at least a contact name or email address.'
         ),
        'emailAddress' => array (
            'last' => TRUE,
            'rule' => array('email', FALSE),
            'message'  => 'A valid Email address is required'
         )
    )
);

// Ensure at least the last name or email field value is provided
function checkOne($field) {
    if(!empty($this->data[$this->User]['last_name']) || 
        !empty($this->data[$this->User]['email'])){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks very much vicocamacho. I kept at it and, in addition to your advice, found the solution also lay in adding a 'required' => false in the view.

Here's the working solution for any one else with this problem:

The model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'last_name'=> array(
        'needOne' => array (
        'rule' => 'checkOne',
        'message' => 'You must enter at least a contact name or email address.'
    ),
    'alphaNumeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
        'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only',
        'allowEmpty' => TRUE
    ),
    'between' => array(
        'rule' => array('between', 2, 45),
        'message' => 'Between 2 to 45 characters',
        'allowEmpty' => TRUE
    )
),
'email' => array(
    'needOne' => array (
        'rule' => 'checkOne',
        'message' => 'You must enter at least a contact name or email address.'
    ),
    'emailAddress' => array (
        'rule' => 'email',
        'message' => 'A valid Email address is required',
        'allowEmpty' => TRUE
    )
)
);

// Ensure at least the last name or email field value is provided
public function checkOne($data) {
    if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['last_name']) 
    || !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['email'])) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The view/fields (I'm using Bootstrap):

```
echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array(
        'required' => false,
        'fieldset' => false,
        'label' => false,
        'before' => '<label class="control-label">Last Name <span class="one-required">*</span></label>',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => 'Last Name',
        'div' => 'form-group col-sm-12',
        'error' => array(
            'attributes' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div', 
                'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
            )
        )
    )
);

echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
        'required' => false,
        'fieldset' => false,
        'label' => false,
        'before' => '<label class="control-label">Email <span class="one-required">*</span></label>',
        'after' => '',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'div' => 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
        'error' => array(
            'attributes' => array(
                'wrap' => 'div', 
                'class' => 'alert alert-danger'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom rule that will check if one of both fields is not empty and use that rule on both fields. And set allowEmpty to true for the other rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should allowEmpty in all the rules that do not check if the fields are present, i updated your code so you can see what i mean, also you need to change the `$this->User` index in your `checkOne` to `$this->alias` otherwise it will always return `false`:

```
public $validate = array(
    'last_name'=> array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule'   => 'alphaNumeric',
            'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        ),
        'between' => array(
            'rule'  => array('between', 2, 45),
            'message' => 'Between 2 to 45 characters',
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'needOne' => array (
            'rule' => 'checkOne',
            'message' => 'You must enter at least a contact name or email address.'
        ),
        'emailAddress' => array (
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message'  => 'A valid Email address is required'
        )
    )
);

// Ensure at least the last name or email field value is provided
function checkOne($field) {
        if(
            !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['last_name']) ||
            !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['email'])
        )
        {
                return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much vicocamacho. I kept at it and, in addition to your advice, found the solution also lay in adding a 'required' => false in the view. I included the solution below (too long to fit as a comment :) ).